# Can't access controller scope from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my app config:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services']);
```

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'world';
  });
```

This is my directive:

```
var directives = angular.module('myApp.directives', []);

directives.directive("hello", function () {
    return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        elm.text("hello, " + scope[attrs.name]);
    };
});
```

and this is my html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1 hello></h1>
</div>
```

The is problem is that angular render the directive as:

> hello, undefined

Instead of:

> hello, world

What is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are accessing `scope[attrs.name]` but the directive doesn't provide a value for the attribute `name`

There are 2 options:

1. Change the directive to `elm.text("hello, " + scope['name']);`
   This is not a preferred way as it hard codes to a scope property name
2. Change the html to `<h1 hello name="name"></h1>`. This is better but I feel it uses a redundant attribute

I would suggest you change the directive to `elm.text("hello, " + scope[attrs['hello']]);`

Or even better `elm.text("hello, " + scope.$eval(attrs['hello']));`

this way you get the benefit of expressions as well(ex: `<h1 hello="name|uppercase"></h1>`)
**[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/94K1ieIJUMXVfZQDi0I7?p=preview)**

This way the html would be `<h1 hello="name"></h1>`

Regarding the attrs parameter: it's nothing more than a map of strings taken from the attributes present on the dom element.

Comment: @vcardillo well add plunker or ask a question :)

Comment: After debugging, I realized my problem was that I was using the `scope: {...}` attribtue in my Directive Definition Object, thereby creating a new isolated scope. I was preventing prototypical inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something that, as of writing this, appears to be undocumented in Angular (see Mark Rajcok's comment here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope).

From within your directive:

```
scope.$parent.name
```

If you do a `console.log(scope)` on the directive's `scope` (from within the directive), you'll see these properties.

All this said, I don't know whether or not this is "proper" Angular convention, due to the fact that this is both undocumented, and I haven't found any other better documentation on how to access the controller that a directive sits within.

Answer (score 3):

You can access using `scope`. Look http://jsfiddle.net/rPUM5/

```
directives.directive("hello", function () {
    return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        elm.text("hello, " + scope.name);
    };
});​
```

Comment: This is really interesting, thanks! I've found very little documentation on using the dot syntax as you have.

Comment: This is really wrong, the `scope` object passed to the linking function is not the same `$scope` a controller instantiates, it's a read-only reference to the scope where the directive is instantiated which should be expressed by `scope`.

Comment: Who said it's the same ? And you can't possibly access the $scope just by writing $scope. It's a violation of the convention just. Putting a $ before scope doesn't mean it's the controller's scope object.

Answer (score 1):

I found another case:

if you are accessing a variable coming from a Ajax request body, then you have to *WAIT until the variable is set*.

e.g:

```
# in controller
$http.get('/preview').then( (response) ->
  $scope.tabs = response.data.tabs
  $scope.master_switch = '1'
  console.info 'after get response in controller'
)

# in directive
directive('masterSwitch', ->
  (scope, element, attrs) ->
    alert 'in directive!'   # will show before "after get response in controller"
    console.info scope.master_switch  # is undefined
    setTimeout( -> console.info(scope.master_switch), 50) # => 1
```